# Coldfusion Open Bluedragon Google App Engine SESSION.SessionName doesn't exist

Tags: google-app-engine, coldfusion

it's weird, but **sometime** I got **SESSION.SessionName doesn't exist**.

any suggestion for fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: session.SessionName has no meaning unless you've created it. You're not confusing it with application.ApplicationName are you?

Comment: I set SESSION.SessionName when user logged in, and delete it when logged out. I don't know why, but sometimes I can't access this SESSION.SessionName, if I wait couple minutes and then reload the page, it exists again. I never got this weird error using Adobe ColdFusion, Railo, or Open BlueDragon (not the GAE version) before

Answer (score 2):

Needs more information.  Where do you set sessionName, and where are you trying to refer to it? A simple StructKeyExists or IsDefined will fix the initial problem.

```
<cfif NOT StructKeyExists(session, "SessionName")>
  <cfset session.SessionName = "foobar">
</cfif>
```

Comment: you provide basic syntax for check existsing session, yes I knew it. please see my comment below Al Everett comment :) thank you for your response

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code, but I suspect un-var scoped variables in your functions.